# JMETER Record a scenario that contains calls using microsoft remote desktop protocol and check 3 party tool activity and come back to application?

Tags: jmeter

My scenario is given as below :
I login into application and upload a doc file then request send to server where thrid party tool (doc to pdf)is running and convert doc file to pdf and send file conversion status pass\fail on application. Can i Record scenarion in JMETER that access microsoft remote desktop protocol and check third party tool activity and come back to application?

Thanks,
Raman

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "record" the RDP protocol the answer is "no", JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) can only record [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) or [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocols, other traffic will not be recognized.

If you want to take some screenshots of the remote Windows machine you can use i.e. [JavaRDP](https://github.com/kaseya/JavaRDP) library from [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

If you need to read the conversion log and add it to JMeter test results it might make more sense to consider connecting to the machine using [PowerShell Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7) from the [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler).

Check out [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/) article for more information on the concept and example configurations.

Comment: ok thanks for your suggestion,can we connect with another server or any alternate solution to achieve this goal?